# How to remove shadow in javafx table view?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I create below style sheet to style my javafx table. Out put almost done but I have some issue

```
.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;


}

.noheader .column-header-background {
    -fx-max-height: 0;
    -fx-pref-height: 0;
    -fx-min-height: 0;
}

.table-row-cell {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-border-color: derive(-fx-base, 20%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0;
}

.table-row-cell {
    -fx-cell-size: 50px;

}

.my-table .table-column {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER-RIGHT;
}
```

After applying this i have a result like below[image]

what i need is remove shadows between rows you can see there is a white and gray shadow behind the table row how can i remove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the answer i have to added few extra css codes

```
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #4d89d3;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: #4d89d3;
}
```

This solved my problem like a charm....